# React i18n - load multiple languages from API

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

my application stores the languages in a Database and **the API manages which languages the client should use** depending on the API request.

the api returns an JSON with the following structure:

```
{
 "en":{...translations},
 "cn":{...translations},
 "jp":{...translations},
}
```

At the moment I'm initializing i18n in this way

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import HttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { languageService } from "services";

const fallbackLng = ["en"];
const { getDictionary } = languageService;

i18n
  .use(HttpBackend) 
  .use(LanguageDetector) 
  .use(initReactI18next) 
  .init({
    fallbackLng,
    backend: {
      allowMultiLoading: true,
      request: (options: any, url: any, payload: any, callback: any) => {
        try {
          getDictionary().then(res => {
            callback(null, {
              data: res,
              status: 200
            });
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          callback(null, {
            status: 500
          });
        }
      },
    }
  });

export const i18nextConfig = i18n;
```

but the resulting i18n store instead of being

```
store: {
  data: {
    en:{...translation },
    cn:{...translation },
  }
}
```

its

```
store: {
  data: {
    en:{ 
      translation:{
        "en":{...translation}, 
        "cn":{...translation}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[i18n store structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY6or.png)

I've been reading the documentation but it seems pretty unclear in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also use the multiload-backend-adapter => https://github.com/i18next/i18next-multiload-backend-adapter